# How do I concatenate each the values of a variable1 with each values of variable2

Tags: php, arrays, string, string-concatenation

// a simpler thing that would get me what I need is:
How do I concatenate each the values of a variable1 with each values of variable2

```
$Var1 = 'my1, my2, my3'; // here I have dozens of entries, they are    symbols
$Var2 = 'word1, word2, word3'; // here also dozens of entries, are words.
```

How do I have all the keys of a variable, placed together of the keys of another variable?

```
$Values_that_I_needed = 'my1word1, my1word2, my1word3, my2word1, my2word2, my2word3, my3word1, my3word2, my3word3';
```

How would I build this values this variable up with all those values without having to type everything!?

Imagine an example with 60 my1, my2 … and 130 word1, word2 …. it’s my case!
Put each of the 60my before each of the 130 words !!
// I need to concatenate / join / join each values / keys of a variable, with all the values/keys of another variable, to avoid making all these combinations by hand. and put in another variable.

Comment: hint: treat them as arrays and iterate.

Comment: What do you mean by "I need to combine each of the values between each key between two arrays"? What's the expected result?

Comment: Hi @k0pernikus , I edited it again to explain it better, it has more space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution using `explode` and `trim` functions:

```
$Var1 = 'my1, my2, my3'; // here I have dozens of entries, they are    symbols
$Var2 = 'word1, word2, word3';
$result = "";
$var2_list = explode(',', $Var2);

foreach (explode(',', $Var1) as $w1) {
    foreach ($var2_list as $w2) {
        $result .= trim($w1) . trim($w2). ', ';
    }
}
$result = trim($result, ', ');
print_r($result);
```

The output:

```
my1word1, my1word2, my1word3, my2word1, my2word2, my2word3, my3word1, my3word2, my3word3
```

Comment: amazing!! awasome!! faster!  #I can do many things with this your help, thank you very much. SOLVED

Comment: It was very good to learn how to combine values into variables, and this will leave me very sure. :) but in my current case, I need to do with arrays, and I asked the question the wrong way here. See my other post please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42360109/i-need-to-combine-each-of-the-values-between-each-key-between-two-arrays?noredirect=1#comment71873470_42360109 Thanks again :-)

Answer (score 0):

Below  cod should work if  var1  and  var2  have the same length

```
<?php
$tab1=explode(',',$var1);
$tab2=explode(',',$var2);

$c=$count($tab1);
$output='';
for($i=0;$i<$c;$i++){
$output.=$tab1[$i].$tab2[$i].', ';
}
echo $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Var1 = 'my1, my2, my3';
$Var2 = 'word1, word2, word3';

$Array1 = explode(", ",$Var1); // create array from $Var1
$Array2 = explode(", ",$Var2); // create array from $Var2

foreach($Array1 as $My){
    foreach($Array2 as $Word){
        $Result[] = $My.$Word; // Join Var1 & Var2
    }
}
$Values_that_I_needed = implode(", ", $Result); 
echo $Values_that_I_needed; // my1word1, my1word2, my1word3, my2word1, my2word2, my2word3, my3word1, my3word2, my3word3
```